# tkinter canvas not opening when while loop is used

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I was experimenting with tkinter and was using the following code as a tester:

```
import keyboard
from time import sleep
from tkinter import *

tk = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(tk, width=400, height=400)
canvas.pack()

a = 0
if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):
    a = 1
if a == 1:
    canvas.create_line(0,0,400,400)
    tk.mainloop()
```

No canvas appears when I run this code. I have tried using a debug message instead of creating a line, as well as shifting "tk.mainloop" but the canvas does not show up. However, when I do not use a while loop but a for loop the canvas appears. The program that I plan on making needs an infinite loop. Is there a way to do this in a way that works with tkinter?

Thanks in advance and my apologies for a question that is probably down to some simple error of mine.

Comment: tkinter already has an infinite loop: `mainloop`. Do some research on the `after` method. There are hundreds of questions and answers on this site related to using loops with tkinter.

Comment: @BryanOakley, if I get rid of the while true loop and just use the mainloop the line still does not get created. Is this because I am using mainloop incorrectly? I apologise again for my total ineptitude here.

Comment: `import keyboard
from time import sleep
from tkinter import *

tk = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(tk, width=400, height=400)
canvas.pack()

a = 0
if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):
    a = 1
if a == 1:
    canvas.create_line(0,0,400,400)
    tk.mainloop()`

Comment: I'm sorry for not being able to include indents in the new code.

Comment: You _should_ use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47984251/edit) button to update your question with the new code/information.

Comment: Sorry, I'll do that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Tkinter` has `bind()` to assign function to key/mouse/event so you don't need `keyboard` module and `while` loop.

```
import tkinter as tk

def myfunction(event):
    canvas.create_line(0, 0, 400, 400)

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=400, height=400)
canvas.pack()

root.bind('q', myfunction)

root.mainloop()
```

---

**EDIT:** something more funny - every `q` create random line

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

def myfunction(event):
    x = random.randint(0, 400)
    y = random.randint(0, 400)
    canvas.create_line(x, y, 400, 400)

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=400, height=400)
canvas.pack()

root.bind('q', myfunction)

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Or like Picasso

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

def myfunction(event):
    x1 = random.randint(0, 400)
    y1 = random.randint(0, 400)
    x2 = random.randint(0, 400)
    y2 = random.randint(0, 400)
    canvas.create_line(x1, y1, x2, y2)

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Picasso')

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=400, height=400)
canvas.pack()

root.bind('q', myfunction)

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I'll use the `bind` function.